# GroupedList in Silverstripe 4, grouped by many_many_extrafield

Tags: php, group-by, many-to-many, field, silverstripe-4

I have two dataobjects related with many_many and an extrafield. My plan is to group the result by the extrafield. Maybe someone has an idea.

```
class Saison extends DataObject {
    private static $db = [
    "Name"=> "Varchar(200)",
    "Jahr" => "Int(4)"
    ];

    private static $many_many = [
    "Team" => Teams::class
    ];

    private static $many_many_extraFields = [
    'Team' => [
            'Gruppe' => 'Varchar'
        ]
    ]; }

class Teams extends DataObject {

    private static $db = [
    "Name" => "Varchar(300)",
    "TeamName" => "Varchar(300)"
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
    ];

    private static $has_many = [
    ];

    private static $belongs_many_many = [
    "Saison"=>Saison::class
    ]; }

function Teams() {

    return GroupedList::create(Saison::get()->filter(array("ID" => $this->Saison()->ID)));

<% loop $Teams %>

<% loop $Team.GroupedBy(Gruppe) %>
$Gruppe<br />
<% end_loop %>

<% end_loop %>
```

With this way I don't get the data.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
Because of the many_many and the belongs_many_many there is a table called Saison_Team. I just created a class Saison_Team which uses this table. So I can use this dataobject and the relations.

Comment: Great that you found a solution, but it sounds like there's probably a better way. If you'd like to update your question with the solution you're using now, perhaps we could help to provide you with a better one

Comment: Sounds like you want to use manymany-through in SS4? https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/relations/#many-many-through-relationship-joined-on-a-separate-dataobject